# A class to load in command line arguments

Tags: c#

Our programs often have to take in command line arguments to load a file from somewhere, specify the mode to run in etc. For this purpose we have developed a class to make it easier to load the arguments in and wrap some further behaviours.

The arguments are in the form `-name:value` with the system being able to specify multiple names if required in a config file.

This is the `CommandLineArgumentsHelper` class:

```
public class CommandLineArgumentsHelper
{
    private string[] _args;
    private CommandLineArgs _commandLineArgs;

    private string _help;

    public Settings Settings { get; }

    public string Help
    {
        get
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_help))
            {
                return _help;
            }

            int nameColumnWidth = Math.Max(4, _commandLineArgs.Arguments.Max(a => a.FriendlyName.Length));
            int argumentNameColumnWidth = Math.Max(14, _commandLineArgs.Arguments.Max(a => String.Join(", ", a.Names).Length));

            _help = $"{"Name".PadRight(nameColumnWidth)}  {"Argument Names".PadRight(argumentNameColumnWidth)}  Description";
            _help += Environment.NewLine + new string('-', _help.Length);

            foreach (Argument argument in _commandLineArgs.Arguments)
            {
                _help += $"{Environment.NewLine}{argument.FriendlyName.PadRight(nameColumnWidth)}  {String.Join(", ", argument.Names).PadRight(argumentNameColumnWidth)}  {argument.Description}";
            }

            return _help;
        }
    }

    public CommandLineArgumentsHelper()
        : this(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray())
    {

    }

    public CommandLineArgumentsHelper(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"The passed in '{nameof(args)}' were either null or empty!");
        }

        _args = args;

        Settings = LoadSystemSettings();
        if (Settings == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Settings), $"The '{nameof(Settings)}' file was unable to be loaded.");
        }

        string argsFile = Path.Combine(Settings.RootPath, "Pars", "Settings", "CommandLineArgs.xml");
        if (!File.Exists(argsFile))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"Was unable to find the file supplied by '{nameof(argsFile)}' at the location '{argsFile}'.", argsFile);
        }

        _commandLineArgs = XmlHelper.Load<CommandLineArgs>(argsFile);
        if (_commandLineArgs == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_commandLineArgs), $"The '{nameof(_commandLineArgs)}' file was unable to be loaded.");
        }
    }

    public string GetArgumentValue(string name, StringComparison stringComparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name), "You must supply a value to the parameter " + nameof(name));
        }

        Argument argument = _commandLineArgs.Arguments.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FriendlyName.Equals(name, stringComparison)
                                                                        || a.Names.Any(n => n.Equals(name, stringComparison)));
        if (argument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(name), "Was unable to find a argument in the settings file with a name of " + name);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(argument.Value))
        {
            argument.Value = _args.FirstOrDefault(a => argument.Names.Any(n => a.StartsWith($"-{n}:", stringComparison)));
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(argument.Value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(argument.FriendlyName), "Was unable to find the relevant argument in the command line arguments.");
            }

            argument.Value = argument.Value.Substring(argument.Value.IndexOf(':') + 1);
        }

        return argument.Value;
    }

    private Settings LoadSystemSettings()
    {
        string pathArg = _args.FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartsWith("-p:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                                || a.StartsWith("-path:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathArg))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The '{nameof(_args)}' must have a path passed in with either: 'p' or 'path'.", nameof(_args));
        }

        string path = pathArg.Substring(pathArg.IndexOf(':') + 1);
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"Was unable to find the file supplied by the '{nameof(_args)}' with the type '{pathArg.Substring(0, pathArg.IndexOf(':'))}' at the location '{path}'.", path);
        }

        return XmlHelper.Load<Settings>(path);
    }
}
```

Where the `XmlHelper` class is just a wrapper around the `XmlSerializer` class. The `Settings` class is a wrapper around an XML file used to specify system settings values. In this case it is used to load the systems root path.

The `CommandLineArgs` class is the class for the XML file is as follows:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class CommandLineArgs
{
    [XmlElement("Argument")]
    public List<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }

    public CommandLineArgs()
    {
        Arguments = new List<Argument>();
    }
}

public class Argument
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public Argument()
    {
        FriendlyName = string.Empty;
        Description = string.Empty;
        Value = string.Empty;
        Names = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a few things:

1. `CommandLineArgumentsHelper` is a bad name for an *instantialble* class. That is, everything in it is non-`static`, so it's not a 'helper' class, it's a utilitarian class. I'd call it `CommandLineArgumentsParser`.
2. `CommandLineArgs` is an acceptable name, **if** you're going to abbreviate the `Parser` / `Serializer` class. Either use `Args` in both, or use `Arguments`.
3. The `args.Length < 1` would get so annoying to me, that I would never use this class. In fact, this whole class is useless to me. You should allow the user to send empty arguments, and consume them, so that I can consume it as follows:

   ```
   var parser = new CommandLineArgsParser(args);
   var file = DEFAULT_FILE;
   var arg = parser.Args.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "File");

   if (arg != null)
   {
       file = arg.Value;
   }
   ```

   Instead of that, though, I have to make sure I only instance the parser *if* all the commands are specified. That's wrong.

   Right now this whole class is *literally* useless for me. If the argument doesn't exist in the passed args, you just *error* on it. There should be a valid state for each argument where it doesn't exist or doesn't get set, because if my command line program supports 50 switches and arguments, my users would be *furious* to have to type that many **every** time.

   Consider reworking the API to be a specialized collection, so that I can call `TryGetValue` and such on it. In fact, I'd consider implementing it like a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, with the exception that `TKey` and `TValue` are `string` implicitly.